# ASP.NET WebApi - random error during serialization of json response

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api

could you guys please help me with this case?

I have an end-point that returns an array of object.

[image]

The problem is that in some cases the json returns a incorrect format. The content-length varies as you can see below

[image]

This difference on the reponse size,  apparently occurs because the Json is bronken in random parts

[image]

The source of the objects returned is a method that make a call in DB and return the result. The result are the same for every requests, the problem appears to happen during the serialization.

**UPDATE**
This is the formatter configuration:

```
private static void ConfigureWebApi(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        var formatters = config.Formatters;
        formatters.Clear();
        formatters.Add(new JsonMediaTypeFormatter());

        var jsonFormatter = formatters.JsonFormatter;
        var settings = jsonFormatter.SerializerSettings;
        settings.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
        settings.ContractResolver = new Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
        settings.ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
        settings.DateTimeZoneHandling = DateTimeZoneHandling.Local;

        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional });
    }
```

Comment: Are you using a custom serializer?

Comment: yes, i'l update the post with my serialization configuration.

Comment: I wonder what the creationDate record looks like in your data source for business plan with id : 3. I know you said it returns the same thing every time, but could it be malformed in a way that's fooling the serializer?

Comment: 201680 is not a correct date format

Comment: that is the point, the serializer put '201680' as value of 'creationDate' erroneously. The object was correct, i've logged it.

Comment: The error occurs in differents properties, each time when the result is serialized. The print in the post is a sample of error that i'm getting